# how to identify JComboBox whether is disabled or enable inside its renderer class

Tags: swing

I have a JComboBox contains following iems

{ "select" , "one" , "two" }

i need a separate background for first item so , 
i have made a condition in it's renderer like

```
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
 boolean cellHasFocus) {

            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            if (value != null){
                Item item = (Item)value;
                setText(item.getDescription());             
            }
            if(index==-1){
                setBackground(new Color(199,209,210));
                setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            }

            return this;
        }
}
```

so my question is if we disable a JComboBox, i have to made -1th index of component background color to someother color

like

```
if(index==-1){

   setBackground(Color.RED);
}
```

please advice

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is always the best. Since you assigning renderer to a combobox, why don't you pass the combobox into it? Just **create a custom renderer that holds the reference to a combobox** then use the stored reference inside of your `getListCellRendererComponent` method

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but if a `JComboBox` is disabled, then that means that it cannot popup its list of items. But if it is not showing its list of items, then that means it is not using the renderer for that list.
So, why do you need to get a reference to the combobox in the renderer?

Comment: Actually renderer is used inside of the "editor" field if combobox is not editable. Here is the proof: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaImages/CustomComboBoxDemo.PNG